# In Quantum Leap, Why Not Send the Displaced Leaper Back?

Tags: quantum-leap

In the Quantum Leap series, Sam Beckett stepped into the Quantum Leap accelerator then vanished and you know the rest of the story, but in episode "The Leap Back - June 15, 1945" Sam and Al switch roles. Al becomes the leaper trapped in the past, facing mirror images that were not his own and Sam becomes the observer from the present. In the episode Al is put into a situation, which causes Sam to decide that he must leap into Al to save his life, which allowed Al to return to the present.

My question is:

**Why not just send the displaced person, who would be in the waiting room, back through the Quantum Leap accelerator, which would allow Sam to return to the present?**

Comment: Because the quantum leap accelerator has proven wildly unsafe for human use?

Answer (score 2):

Because this episode has a lot of plot holes.  The previous episode had a lightning strike at the time of leaping, but as it is only the consciousness that actually travels, it does not explain how the communicator that Al carries manages to travel to 1945, to answer your question though if Sam has leaped into Al's body in the imaging chamber, and Tom is in Sam's body in the waiting room, the only way to get Al back into his own body is to use the accelerator again, to do a 3 way switch Tom into his body, Al into his and Sam off to whoever is next.  The reason they couldn't do as you asked is because normally they can't control the leaps, that's why Al is never there straight away when he leaps, they have to search the timeline for him.  Also because the leap is restricted to Sam's timeline, sending someone else back through could send them to a point of time outside of Sams timeline and then they might never find him.

Answer (score 2):

In the episode "A Leap For Lisa" (the last episode of Season 4), which takes place after "The Leap Back", they tried doing exactly that - they leaped young Al (Bingo) into himself before the road accident which triggered the whole sequence of events, and like magic all those who had been killed were restored to life and Sam/Bingo was free. So this leap clearly worked. But logically, Sam should have returned home and Al's memories of events should have changed. There was no in-universe explanation offered.

Maybe the answer lies in the Lee Harvey Oswald episode. Sam's and Oswald's identites had blurred together, making Sam act as Oswald had. Al and Gushie tried leaping Oswald back into himself, but the result was that the blurring got worse and Sam was even less able to control his actions. So perhaps in the Leap For Lisa instance, leaping Bingo back into himself did not result in a clean switch, but in a half-and-half state which the Quantum Leap techies couldn't resolve, and only by leaping "naturally" could the threads become untangled. Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that, when Sam leaped into Al, he then went on and leaped again.

Every time someone leaps, they wind up stuck leaping through time. So, if they sent the other person through, they'd eventually leap into someone else. And then you'd have the same problem as before--a time traveler loose across time, away from their home--except now it would be worse, as they wouldn't know what they were doing or what was going on. And, even if they figure it out, they may not have the same good intentions as Sam, and screw the timeline up even more.

So, while Sam could possibly come home, it would only create a whole new problem they've have to deal with--possibly worse than the original.